# Asp.Net Dropdownlist Set Item View limit

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, asp.net-controls

I have a country DropDownList in Asp.Net Page.I Bind DropDownList from Database. it gives me 239 item. and it is very large scroll in page.

so, my Question how to set 10 item in Dropdown and then scroll in List.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcountry" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
     runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: You can try DropDownList1.Attributes.Add("Size", "10"); OR Why not use aspnet ListBox instead? ListBox provides an auto scrollbars when the item is larger than the size of the List

Answer (score 4):

Actually this is very interesting and tricky task , we need to do some configuration and apply some css for this

Since <kbd>[DropDownList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx)</kbd>  does not have inbuilt scroll bars so we need to do it manually by using `OnMouseDown, OnFocusOut,OnDblClick` properties

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcountry" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
     runat="server" 
     CssClass="DDlCountry"  
     OnMouseDown="this.size=5;" 
     OnFocusOut="this.size=1;" 
     OnDblClick="this.size=1;">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Add new CSS Class for this `DDlCountry`

```
.DDlCountry {
        width: 128px;
        margin: 0 15px 0 0;
        font: 12px tahoma;
        max-height: 200px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in two ways.

One is,

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="50px" 
Style="position: static"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

or

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" size="10" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: both proposed solutions are irrelevant to the question asked and do not generate the required output

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Size` attribute

```
<asp:DropDownList Size="10" ID="ddlcountry" AutoPostBack="true"  AppendDataBoundItems="true"
 runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response..but size attribute not working.

Answer (score 0):

Why use scrolling use **select2** search plugins.

[Select2 Example](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

1.Reference select2.css and select2.js in your .aspx file

2.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProductSubType" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="">Select</asp:ListItem>

                                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

3.

```
  <script>
      $(function() {
          $('#ddlProductSubType').select2({
              placeholder: 'select a state',
              //tags: "true",
              //allowClear: true,
              theme: "classic"
          });
});
  </script>
```

N.B i have used it and it respond well upto 3,000 dropdown list items.If you want to filter/on demand loading , option is there in select2 documentation